# What (semantic?) markup should one use to indicate a known dead link? (clarification: a dead URL displayed as text)

Tags: html, hyperlink, semantic-markup

I have a page where I'm going to list several links to sites that are long gone, but may be stored in archives or otherwise be identified by their old URLs. Is there a way I can express this idea in HTML?

Comment: Cursory search provided nothing and I've personally never heard of any semantic markup for a dead link. If at possible your hyperlinks should be functional, so if I were in your shoes I'd point the link towards the archived site and have the inner text (between the a brackets) be the original url or site name.

Comment: The URLs are for historical purposes-I don't want to prejudice readers by giving them links to, say, the internet archive when another archive (a giant geocities backup for example) might be more appropriate. Just to clarify, I'm going to display the dead link directly, not put a hyperlink to a nonexistent page.

Comment: Your somment says that you are not going to have a dead link but instead a URL of a page that once existed. This is different from what the question itself says. A URL is not a link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend the `<s>` element. The [HTML5 spec says](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/text-level-semantics.html#the-s-element)

> The s element represents contents that are no longer accurate or no
>   longer relevant.

So you could do

```
<s class="dead-link">http://example.com/dead-link</s>
```

By default, the text will typically be struck through, so if you don't want that, add CSS to the effect of

```
s.dead-link { text-decoration: none }
```

By this way, you can add an `<a>` element around the `<s>` element if you have a link to an archived copy of the page and thus distinguish that it is the old URL which is no longer accurate, from the archive link, which is.

Or, if you don't have a link to an archived copy, you can omit the `<a>` element, and still express the idea that the URL is no longer accurate.

Comment: Although `s` means  such a thing according to the HTML5 draft, all existing HTML recommendations define it simply as overstriking (physical markup). So HTML5 is just trying to save this element by assigning a “semantic” meaning to it. There is no evidence of browsers or search engine treating it according to such a meaning. And logically speaking, if you use it for dead links, you should wrap the `a` element inside `s`, not vice versa. It’s the link, rather than the link text, that is “no longer accurate”.

Comment: I want to display the link as text-it's primary purpose is for users to see and recognize the URL, not attempt to navigate to it.

Answer (score 2):

HTML has no built-in defined markup for this purpose.

I usually update the link to either a local mirror or [the wayback machine](https://archive.org/web/).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`hidden` attribute](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/editing.html#the-hidden-attribute):

> The hidden attribute is a boolean attribute. When specified on an
>   element, it indicates that **the element is** not yet, or is **no longer**,
>   directly **relevant** to the page's current state, or that it is being
>   used to declare content to be reused by other parts of the page as
>   opposed to being directly accessed by the user.

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

In your stylesheet, you must display them because will be hidden by default.

```
<a class="dead-link" hidden href="//example.com">Link</a>
```

```css
.dead-link {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Great answer! I think it might be even better to go a step further and add an `onclick="return false"` in there as well, just in case the URL has been re-purposed into something malicious or irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

This answer extends on [Oriol's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23985291/1317805) which makes use of [HTML's `hidden` attribute](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/editing.html#the-hidden-attribute).

## The `hidden` attribute

> The hidden attribute is a boolean attribute. **When specified on an element, it indicates that the element is not yet, or is no longer, directly relevant to the page's current state**, or that it is being used to declare content to be reused by other parts of the page as opposed to being directly accessed by the user.

First things first, the `hidden` attribute isn't present in the HTML401 specification. It makes its first appearance in the HTML5 Candidate Recommendation. This means that any HTML document which makes use of this attribute must include the [HTML5 doctype](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#the-doctype):

```
<!doctype html>
```

The `hidden` attribute can then be used as follows:

```
<a href="http://example.com" hidden> ... </a>
```

Browsers handle the `hidden` attribute with CSS, doing nothing more than setting `display: none` on it. If you look at [**this JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/89hmY/) (which uses nothing more than the above markup), you should see that the `<a>` element isn't rendered within the results pane.

---

## Styling the dead link

We can override this with our own CSS. There are many ways this can be done, however as you've accepted [Alohci's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23985770/1317805) which makes use of HTML's `<s>` element I'm going to assume you want the link to appear with a line through it. For this we can use CSS's `text-decoration` property, targetting the `hidden` attribute specifically:

```css
a[hidden] {
    color: inherit;                   /* Inherit the color from the parent. */
    display: inline;                  /* Make the link visible. */
    text-decoration: line-through;    /* Put a line throguh it. */
}
```

Note how I've also given the `color` property a value of `inherit` - this overrides the link's default colour with that of the parent. This is used to make the link appear as regular text within its container.

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/89hmY/1/).

---

## Handling the dead link

Ideally we should now take this a step further by preventing the user from being taken to the URL specified within the dead link. This is a security measure in the event that the URL has been re-purposed into something else; after all, you wouldn't want to risk having the content on your website linking to something malicious.

As [Quentin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23985208/1317805) has suggested, you can make your link point to a local mirror or the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/web/), however this may not always work as you may not have a local mirror and the archive may not have any results for that page.

There are a few options which I think may work well:

### Option 1: Blocking the link from opening

If we introduce some JavaScript we can block our link from opening simply by adding an `onclick` attribute to our markup:

```
<a href="http://example.com" hidden onclick="return false"> ... </a>
```

Now when a user clicks on the link, nothing will happen. However this doesn't really let the user know what's going on, so instead we can turn it into a JavaScript function which asks the user whether they want to follow the link:

```
<a href="http://example.com" hidden onclick="return deadLink(this)"> ... </a>
```

```js
function deadLink(obj, event) {   
    var
        // Get the URL from the link
        href = obj.href,
        
        // Set the message we want to display to the user
        message = "This link no longer points to the page it was originally" + 
                  "intended for.\n\n" + href + "\n\n" +
                  "Do you want to follow the link anyway?";
    
    /* Pass the message into a confirmation dialog to determine
     * whether the user wants to follow the link or not. */
    return confirm(message);
}
```

This presents the user with the following dialog:

[image: Dialog Example]

Clicking "OK" will cause the `confirm()` function to return `true`, telling the browser to follow the link. Clicking "Cancel" will return `false`, preventing the link from opening.

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/89hmY/3/).

The problem with this approach is that it will not work for users which have JavaScript disabled. Therefore we may want to do something else...

### Option 2: Setting up a separate "dead link" page on your own website

A better option might be instead to create a new "dead link" page on your website which could:

1. Inform the user what a dead link is.
2. Let the user copy the URL to their clipboard.
3. Give the user options for loading the page, such as linking to a local mirror or to the Internet Archive as mentioned above.

```html
<a href="http://example.org/dead-link?url=http://example.com" hidden> ... </a>
```

Here `http://example.org/dead-link` is your "dead link" page set up on your own website and `http://example.com` is the dead URL we're passing to the page through its `url` query string.